# How to use the title attribute as the content for Tippy.js?

Tags: tippyjs

I have some tooltips that are set up like this:

HTML:

```
<button id="myButton" title="This is a tooltip">My Button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
tippy('#myButton', {
  content: "Some stuff",
});
```

Is there any way I can set the `content:` to use the contents of the `title=` attribute as the contents of the tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/all-props/#content), you can use `reference.getAttribute('title')`

Ex.:

```
tippy('#myButton, {
  content: (reference) => reference.getAttribute('title'),
});
```